# A famous propositions on Dirichlet characters

Tags: analytic-number-theory

can you offer a proof for this proposition?

$$\frac{1}{d}\sum_{o(\chi )|d} {\chi (u) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{1 \quad \text{if u is a dth power resedue modulo p}}\\
{0 \quad \text{otherwise}}
\end{array}} \right.}$$

$o(\chi)=d$ means order of $\chi$ modulo $p$ is $d$.

Comment: Why is [this proposition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908832/a-proposition-about-dirichlet-characters-of-order-d-module-n?rq=1) not famous, too?

Comment: see what I did [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1860121/276986) using a discrete logarithm modulo $p$ for expliciting the $\chi$ modulo a prime $p$ (if $p$ is not prime, the concept of discrete logarithm becomes a little more complicated)

Comment: Oh, I don't want to reject it. But why analytic proof? What about an algebraic proof?

Comment: not convinced you can avoid the discrete logarithm ; it is  a bijection / group isomorphism $h : (\mathbb{F}_p^*,\times) \to (\mathbb{Z}_{p-1},+)$. So $u = x^d$ becomes $h(u) = d \ h(x)$. And the $\chi$ become the discrete Fourier basis on $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$

Comment: @user356319 what do you mean ? and if you don't use the discrete logarithm then you have to use it implicitely, namely that $(\mathbb{F}_p^*,\times)$ is a cyclic group isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_{p-1},+)$

Comment: can you write what would be the analogous of your formula when replacing $(\mathbb{Z}_p^*,\times)$ by $(\mathbb{Z}_{p-1},+)$ and $\chi(n)$ by $e^{2 i \pi k n/(p-1)}$ (the basis of the discrete Fourier transform) ?

Comment: @user356319 maybe that's why you don't know how to prove your formula