# Formula Related To Primitive Root Of A Prime

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to understand a paper of P. Erdos and H. N. Shapiro, named as "On The Least Primitive Root Of A Prime". There they have used a function like the following:

$P(t)= \sum\limits_{d|p-1} \dfrac{\mu(d)}{\phi(d)}\sum\limits_{o(\chi)=d}\chi(t)$; where $\chi$ is any non-principal character modulo a prime $p$, $\mu$ is the Mobius function and $\phi$ is the Euler's Totient Function. Next they said that - if $t$ is not a primitive root modulo $p$, then $P(t)=0$. But how?

Note that, $t$ is called a primitive root modulo $p$, if order of $t$ is $(p-1)$. I am completely clueless. Please give any hint or provide any related formula which I can use.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860079/a-formula-involving-order-of-dirichlet-characters-mun-and-varphin

Comment: Thanks @Phicar. I am going to read these solutions.